# Isometric view of the given figure

Tags: drawings

[image: my try]
Draw the isometric view of the given diagram.
I have added my trial and I am unable to think how exactly the final diagram will look like. Please help me.
[[image: Question picture is givenMy try]

Comment: We won't do it for you as that would lose the learning opportunity but we'll help you along. What do you think the 40 x 20 rectangle would look like on your isometric? Draw it in and add the update into your question. Tip: Crop the photo before uploading. >75% of your first image is irrelevant.

Comment: How's the grade of your homework turned out, pass or not?

Comment: Thanks for help it was great

Answer (score -2):

The proportions are wrong intentionally but the part should look something like the following:

[image]

Comment: -1 for handing out a solution to a homework problem.

Answer (score -2):

For fun, this is my try. Not to scale though.

[image]